# Structured query over M to M in NDB

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gql

My model is like this

- Club
- User
- Course

  - reference to club (key)
- Session

  - reference to Course (key)
- ClubMembership

  - reference to club (key)
  - reference to user (key)
- CourseSubscription

  - reference to course (key)
  - reference to user (key)

Now, i want to have all the `course`s i'm subscribed to, having as input a `club` and a `user`

what i did is:

```
courses = Courses(Courses.club == club.key).fetch(keys_only=True)
real_list = []
for course in courses:
   if CourseSubscription.get_by_id(user, course):
       real_list.append(course)
sessions = Session.query(Session.course.IN(real_list),Session.start_date >= start_date).fetch()
```

for CourseSubscription i used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26746542/1257185, this is why i can do the if (yet it's expensive)

is there a better way to do it? at least less expensive. i was thinking of gql, but then i've a list of `IN` to do.
probably smt like:
`select key from courseSubscription, where course.club = {clubid} and user = {user}` then a `ndb_get_multi` to load the query results?
is this possible somehow?

Comment: GQL does not provide *any* additional functionality or efficiency over db/ndb.

Comment: so is there any better solution (in NDB) than the one i did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop makes a number of requests and you can combine them into a single request.

If your `CourseSubscription` is the same as the `CourseInscription` in your SO link above, then you could get a list of subscription keys and make a single `get_multi()` call to get all of the subscriptions:

```
subscription_keys = [ndb.Key(CourseSubscription, CourseSubscription.build_id(user, course))
                     for course in courses]
real_list = ndb.get_multi(subscription_keys)
```

If the key does not exist, then that subscription will be `None`.  You will have to filter those out.

Comment: didn't test but seems very good indeed. the `None` will be in `real_list`, correct? if so what's the best way to remove `None` from a list? i guess probably it's this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16096769/1257185

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best way: `real_list = [s for s in ndb.get_multi(subscription_keys) if s is not None]`