# Building personalized feed on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I have been working on a social app. I'll first explain the problems, and then summarize in the questions below.

In the network, there would be channels, and users. Users can subscribe to these channels, and to other users. This way, we have two sources from which posts can be generated.

Now, we can simply keep one Activity model where we record all the actions, their kind, and what they affect. Be it from channels, or from the users. And refer these while creating a feed for each user.

I found a solution given in a  [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8) by Brett Slatkin which basically suggests using ListProperty to link each post with each subscriber. But [Guido suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418435/2084082) not to use lists if there's going to be more than 1000 elements. So if there's going to be more than 1000 subscribers to a channel, this will probably run into problem. Even if this were to work --

I want to rank the posts based on popularity (based on number of votes, comments), and apply some time decay function. More like Reddit. To do so, I will have to keep the Activity in memory, and filter and order it based on ranks for each user. I'll also need to do it periodically since new activities will keep occurring also old activities will gain, or lose their values.

The challenge is -- To keep the data in memory (for processing the feed as well as to keep things fast). I will have to store a copy of each users feed to persistent storage, but if the order of posts is going to be changing, how do I keep track of that in the database?

Also: *I have kept my options open -- I will move to AWS if I have to.*

**To summarize:**

1. Is there a better solution to keep track of subscribers without using Lists? Using something like PostID > SubscriberID in one entity would be *very, very* expensive and inefficient.
2. If there's any cost-effective and fast solution to the problem above, how do I deal with the next challenge -- which is to generate a personalized feed? (memory issues - unknown size of memcache)
3. If I can generate a personalized feed (which will be dynamic, will be changing) how to I keep it in the database?.

I have gone through several articles and I can probably solve first two problems with AWS, but I am trying to stay away from the manual scaling work. If there is no way, I am willing to move to AWS. Even if I move to AWS, I can't think of a solution to the third problem.

Any thoughts, directions, resources would be helpful! Thanks!